# Multiple Core Animation Viewports

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation, calayer

I have a complex structure of CALayers forming a motion graphics system that can be manipulated by the user. This is being displayed in the main window as a part of the UI. I am looking for a good way to display multiple small sections of the CALayer stack on a second display as "viewports", which will likely be at a higher resolution that the main view. I am aware that I could render them out and redraw them, but want to maintain the resolution independence of the CALayers.

My thought process was something to the effect of adding the main CALayer to multiple superlayers and then using a combination of masks and transforms to get the viewport to display the portion needed. Unfortunately, a CALayer can only have one superlayer.

Is there any good way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you'll need to maintain multiple `CALayer` stacks, one for each view. Since all the sets of layers should just be reflecting the state of a single model it should be relatively straightforward to keep them in sync.

You could optimise the zoomed view to only manage layers that are actually visible, which would cut down on resource usage.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was hoping someone might know something I missed. I'll head down this path. Thanks!